# How to filter system applications?

Tags: android, filter

I want to filter system app only using their package name.  How can I do this?

I know the below function filter the system app, but as I said above only using package name.

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo)
{
    return (pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
}
```

Comment: If you provide usecase, it would help in answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i do this?

You don't. It is not possible. There is no package naming convention for "system apps".

Answer (score 0):

> only using package name

You can filter out the system apps based on package names, but you will eventually always need the **ApplicationInfo** of the app.

You could use this method:

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(String packageName){
    PackageManager packageManager = MyActivity.this.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
    try {
        applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ((applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
            : false;
}
```